# JMock triggers AssertionError: invokation expected once, never invoked - but it has been invoked

Tags: junit, jmock

I'm pretty new to programming with java but I've tried to directly start with unit-testing and therefore also used JMock. I have already implemented some test-cases (with JMock) that work, but this one I just can't get to run.

What I did:
I wrote a test-class which creates a mock object and then I'm expectation one (using oneOf) invocation. After running the unit test it says it fails (but the logs say otherwise, as i print out the data I returned at the invocation using `will(returnValue(x))`.

The next funny/weird thing is - if I change the oneOf to "never" the unit test succeeds, but it throws an Exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.AssertionError: unexpected invocation: blockingQueue.take()
```

expectations:
  expected never, never invoked: blockingQueue.take(); returns 
what happened before this: nothing!

Here the code:

```
@RunWith(JMock.class)
public class ExecuteGameRunnableTest {
    private Mockery context = new JUnit4Mockery();
    private Thread testObject;
    private BlockingQueue<Game> queueMock;
    private Executor executorMock;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        queueMock = context.mock(BlockingQueue.class);
        executorMock = context.mock(Executor.class);
        testObject = new Thread(new ExecuteGameRunnable(queueMock, executorMock, true));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        queueMock = null;
        executorMock = null;
        testObject = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testQueueTake() throws InterruptedException {
        final Game game = new Game();
        game.setId(1);
        game.setProcessing(false);
        context.checking(new Expectations() {{
            never(queueMock).take(); will(returnValue(game));
        }});
        testObject.start();
        context.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

and the runnable that I'm testing:

```
public class ExecuteGameRunnable implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<Game> queue;
    private Executor executor;
    private Boolean unitTesting = false;
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExecuteGameRunnable.class);

    public ExecuteGameRunnable(BlockingQueue<Game> queue, Executor executor) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    public ExecuteGameRunnable (BlockingQueue<Game> queue, Executor executor, Boolean unitTesting) {
        this(queue,executor);
        this.unitTesting = unitTesting;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            do {
                if (Thread.interrupted()) throw new InterruptedException();
                Game game = queue.take();
                logger.info("Game "+game.getId()+" taken. Checking if it is processing"); // THIS ONE PRINTS OUT THE GAME ID THAT I RETURN WITH JMOCK-FRAMEWORK
                if (game.isProcessing()) {
                    continue;
                }
                game.updateProcessing(true);

                executor.execute(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
            } while (!unitTesting);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            logger.info("Game-Execution-Executor interrupted.");
            return;
        } catch (DataSourceException ex) {
            logger.fatal("Unable to connect to DB whilst executing game: "+id_game,ex);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just ran that code and the test passes

Comment: strange, I got it running right now using: http://www.jmock.org/threading-executor.html

Answer (score 1):

JMock isn't thread safe. It's intended to support unit testing, rather than what is a very small integration test. Frankly, in this case I'd use a real `BlockingQueue` rather than a mock one. And there is no way you should have a `unitTesting` flag in your production code.

One more thing, you don't need to set the fields in the test class to null, jUnit flushes the instance for every test.